# How to check for a particular range of keys exists in json string or not

Tags: c#, json

I have the following json string data as input:

```
string json="{"-1":0,"78":6,"79":6,"80":2,"81":16777215,"82":16777215,"83":1,"84":0,"85":0,"86":"2023/05/07","87":0,"88":0,"89":1,"90":1,"124":1,"16":5,"17":null,"18":null,"19":0,"20":2,"21":2000,"22":0,"23":0,"24":0,"25":0,"26":0,"109":0,"110":0,"29":0,"30":0,"31":0,"32":2000,"33":13710,"34":15710,"135":null}"
```

I want to check if any of the key above has other than from 1 to 150 so that it can return false. How can I achieve this in c#. **Condition: I don't want to use Json Deserializer here. I have tried with `jSon.Contains("\"-1\":")`
   This works only for one key i,e: -1 . Instead what I want is that from 1 to 150

Comment: Why don’t you want to deserialized?

Comment: You'll have to write the logic to parse the string then, which is what the deserializer would help you with.

Comment: @Black Frog This whole logic is written in the SSIS Script component. Because deserialize uses newtonsoft dll whose  import  inside the script component  is cumbersome. Can anyone help with >                                  
 jSon.Contains("\"-1\":") here i want a range from 1 to 150 rather than -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you wouldn't try to parse this your self, however since you can't use a parser, I guess you could do this using `Regex`

**Given**

```
var input = "{\"-1\":0,\"78\":6,\"79\":6,\"80\":2,\"81\":16777215,\"82\":16777215,\"83\":1,\"84\":0,\"85\":0,\"86\":\"2023/05/07\",\"87\":0,\"88\":0,\"89\":1,\"90\":1,\"124\":1,\"16\":5,\"17\":null,\"18\":null,\"19\":0,\"20\":2,\"21\":2000,\"22\":0,\"23\":0,\"24\":0,\"25\":0,\"26\":0,\"109\":0,\"110\":0,\"29\":0,\"30\":0,\"31\":0,\"32\":2000,\"33\":13710,\"34\":15710,\"135\":null}";
```

---

## Option 1

```
var isOutOfRange = Regex.Matches(input, @"""-?\d+""")
                        .Cast<Match>()
                        .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Value.Trim('"')))
                        .Any(x => x < 1 || x > 150);
```

**Explanation**

[image]

[image]

---

## Option 2

With *negative* and *positive lookbehind* (which removes the *Quotes*)

```
var isOutOfRange = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<="")-?\d+(?<!"")")
                        .Cast<Match>()
                        .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Value))
                        .Any(x => x < 1 || x > 150);
```

**Explanation**

[image]

**Update**

From Comments [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) suggested that it might be prudent to check for the colon in the case one of the values are encased in quotes

In that case you could probably modify the patters to the following

```
"-?\d+"(?=:)
(?<=")-?\d+(?<!":)
```

Comment: What do you think about suggesting `(?=:)`, as a possible workaround if there's a chance that also the values on right might appear (hypothetically) enclosed in double quotes?

Comment: But this doesn't recognise "special characters" as I have tested it

Comment: @nagaraj What are special characters

Comment: @TheGeneral special characters like @

Comment: @nagaraj do you mean there are special characters in your input? and this answer is not working?

Comment: yes if input contains special character ex: "{\"@\":0,\"78\":6}" then it wont recognise it

Comment: @nagaraj but how is a  numeric character grater or less than "@", you really need to update your question with thr exact specifics of your problem